# How to update contents of ArrayList in AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

What I am trying to do is get a list of names out of my json file and store it into an ArrayList. I implement a class called ServiceHandler with a method getPointsList() to do so. All of the values and object passing seems to be correct so I am wondering if it is a problem with me running AsyncTask. The error log seems to return a NullPointerException statement 
Here is **Service Handler**

```
public class ServiceHandler {
    private static String pt_url="full url name here";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_LON = "gps_lon";
    private static final String TAG_LAT = "gps_lat";

ArrayList<String> PList;

static String response = null;
public final static int GET = 1;
public final static int POST = 2;
static InputStream is= null;
static JSONObject jObj=null;
ProgressDialog pDialog;
Activity A;
JSONArray json;

public ServiceHandler(Activity A) {
    this.A=A;
}

/**
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
    return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
}

/**
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * @params - http request params
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {
    try {
        // http client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            // adding post params
            if (params != null) {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                        .format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        }
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;

}

public ArrayList<String> getPointsList() throws JSONException{
    GetPoints AT = new GetPoints();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(A);
    pDialog.setMessage("Retreiving points...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();
    AT.execute(pt_url);

    PList = new ArrayList<String>();
    int i;
    Log.d("",""+AT.getStatus());
```

**if I remove the ! it will never pass through the if statement, the problem is with AsyncTask running continiously**

```
if(!(AT.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED))){
            if (pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
            Log.d("Status: ",AT.getStatus().toString());
            for (i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i("Name of Object: "+i,c.getString(TAG_NAME));
                PList.add(c.getString(TAG_NAME));
                //LatList.add(c.getDouble(TAG_LAT));
                //LonList.add(c.getDouble(TAG_LON));
            }
        }
        return PList;
    }

    public class GetPoints extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONArray>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            /*pDialog = new ProgressDialog(A);
            pDialog.setMessage("Retreiving points...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show(); */
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... arg){
            //ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            //Log.i("arg[0]",arg[0]);
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String ptStr = makeServiceCall(arg[0], GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + ptStr);

            if (ptStr != null) {
                try {
                    json = new JSONArray(ptStr); 
                    //Log.d("New json: ", json.toString());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url"); 
                //PList.add("some text");
            }
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result){
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //Log.d("New json: ", json.toString());
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            /*if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();*/
            //for(String entry: PList){
            //  Log.i("GETPOINTS", entry);  
            //  }

            /* Adapters are updated here, so change this to fit whatever we use in UI
            stAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, FList);
            festAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            inputFest.setAdapter(festAdapter);
                            */
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the **ERROR LOG**

```
    04-03 02:22:37.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18824): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 02:22:37.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18824): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-03 02:22:37.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at com.example.demo.ServiceHandler.getPointsList(ServiceHandler.java:123)
04-03 02:22:37.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at com.example.demo.MainMenuActivity$2.onClick(MainMenuActivity.java:70)
04-03 02:22:37.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4198)
04-03 02:22:37.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17158)
04-03 02:22:37.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-03 02:22:37.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-03 02:22:37.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-03 02:22:37.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
04-03 02:22:37.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 02:22:37.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-03 02:22:37.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
04-03 02:22:37.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
04-03 02:22:37.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-03 02:22:37.680: D/Response:(18824): > [{"id":"5","name":"The Hendrix Center","gps_lat":"34.67605277777778","gps_lon":"-82.831825","campus_id":"1"},{"id":"7","name":"Red Fern","gps_lat":"34.67575","gps_lon":"-82.83358055555556","campus_id":"1"},{"id":"9","name":"McAdams Hall","gps_lat":"34.67559166666666","gps_lon":"-82.83461388888888","campus_id":"1"},{"id":"10","name":"Edwards Hall","gps_lat":"34.67681666666667","gps_lon":"-82.83379166666666","campus_id":"1"},{"id":"11","name":"Vickory Hall","gps_lat":"34.677375","gps_lon":"-82.83379722222222","campus_id":"1"},{"id":"12","name":"Daniel Hall","gps_lat":"34.67714722222222","gps_lon":"-82.8351611111111","campus_id":"1"},{"id":"13","name":"Kinard Hall","gps_lat":"34.677524999999996","gps_lon":"-82.83515","campus_id":"1"},{"id":"14","name":"Martin Hall","gps_lat":"34.67805833333333","gps_lon":"-82.83553055555555","campus_id":"1"}]
```

Comment: what is the line number 123?

Comment: do you debug the app and find where you are getting nullpointer

Comment: The problem is in that for loop on line 123 since AsyncTask seems to never finish, which means that json stays null. So the problem must be in AsyncTask not ending.

Comment: it's not entirely clear where your AT.getStatus check code is being executed? Any reason you are not just using the postExecute method to run that code (then you don't need the AT status check, as the method is invoked once the toInBackground is complete

Answer (score 1):

In getPointsList() you do this:

```
for (i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
```

The variable json is null because the ASyncTask is not finished yet.

Comment: Yeah that is why I try using (AT.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED))

Comment: AsyncTask is stuck running continuously somehow, but when I print to Log in onPostExecute() it has no problem. So it is my assuption that AsyncTask is hitting the final method of its execution.